# How to write into a char array in C at specific location using sprintf?

Tags: c, arrays, string, matlab, printf

I am trying to port some code written in MATLAB to C, so that I can compile the function and execute it faster (the code is executed very often and it would bring a significant speed increase).

So basically what my MATLAB code does it that it takes a matrix and converts it to a string, adding brackets and commas, so I can write it to a text file. Here's an idea of how this would work for a vector MyVec:

```
MyVec = rand(1,5);
NbVal = length(MyVec)
VarValueAsText = blanks(2 + NbVal*30 + (NbVal-1));
VarValueAsText([1 end]) = '[]';
VarValueAsText(1 + 31*(1:NbVal-1)) = ',';
for i = 1:NbVal
   VarValueAsText(1+(i-1)*31+(1:30)) = sprintf('%30.15f', MyVec(i));
end
```

Now, how can I achieve a similar result in C? It doesn't seem too difficult, since I can calculate in advance the size of my string (char array) and I know the position of each element that I need to write to my memory area. Also the `sprintf` function exists in C. However, I have trouble understanding how to set this up, also because I don't have an environment where I can learn easily by trial and error (for each attempt I have to recompile, which often leads to a segmentation fault and MATLAB crashing...).

I hope someone can help even though the problem will probably seem trivial, but I have have very little experience with C and I haven't been able to find an appropriate example to start from...

Comment: Maybe if you show us some sample input (say: a 4*4 matrix), things would be easier. (do you want to use an on-disk file as intermediate storarage, or do you want an in-memory interface?) Note: in C, sprintf() has as a first argument the string/buffer where the results should go, I don't expect matlab to be very different in this. Note2: there does not a appear to be a delimiter (space, tab, comma, newline) in your result string.

Comment: Hi & Thanks for replying! I'm not sure I understand your comment though: the code I've put is the current (working) code in MATLAB which I'm trying to port to C. Actually, I've added the first line (with the random input) as a sample input. At the end I get my "formatted values" in VarValuesAsString...

Comment: I don't know anything about mathlab. It appears though as if you want the resulting string to be `[val1,val2,val3,...]` is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `sprintf` will put a string-terminator at the end of the string it prints, so if the string you "print" into should be longer than the string you print, then that won't work.

So if you just want to overwrite part of the string, you should probably use `sprintf` to a temporary buffer, and then use `memcpy` to copy that buffer into the actual string. Something like this:

```
char temp[32];
sprintf(temp, "...", ...);

memcpy(&destination[position], temp, strlen(temp));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights! I had successfully managed to write my variables at the correct place in the final string, but the output string was limited to the first element: the key to the answer was indeed not to include the string-terminator!!!

Answer (score 6):

Given an offset (in bytes) into a string, retrieving a pointer to this offset is done simply with:

```
char *ptr = &string[offset];
```

If you are iterating through the lines of your matrix to print them, your loop might look as follow:

```
char *ptr = output_buffer;
for (i = 0; i < n_lines; i++) {
    sprintf (ptr, "...", ...);
    ptr = &ptr[line_length];
}
```

Be sure that you have allocated enough memory for your output buffer though.

Comment: As long as sprintf and snprintf are successful, they will return the number of characters written into the string. You can use this return value to calculate the offset as well. char *ptr = output_buffer; positionToWrite += sprintf(positionToWrite, "...", ...);